# Can I hide the "Map created by {user}" element in a iframe visualization?

Tags: carto

I would like hide the "Map created by {user}" element that its show when you use iframe embed.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove that if your pricing plan has the "Removable brand" option (Coronelli and Mercator plans and Enterprise account). If that's the case, go to your map, click on "Options" and uncheck the "CartoDB Logo" option.